# Can't find out why vuex getters ById doensim get a company by id

Tags: vue.js, store, vuex

i am still new to VUEX and i am following this tutorial [vuex store](https://scotch.io/courses/build-an-online-shop-with-vue)
The only thing i am doing differently is i am using sequelize instead of mLab like he does.

This is what my getters look like

```js
export const companyGetters = {

allCompanies: (state, getters) => {
  return state.companies
},

companyById: (state, getters) => id => {
  if (getters.allCompanies.length > 0) {

    return getters.allCompanies.filter(c => c._id === id)[0]
  } else {
    return state.company
  }
}
```

Exactly like what he did.

My action looks like this

```js
companyById ({commit}, payload) {
    commit(COMPANY_BY_ID)
    axios.get(`${API_BASE}/companies/${payload}`).then(response => {
      console.log(payload, response.data)
      commit(COMPANY_BY_ID_SUCCESS, response.data)
    })
  }
```

Next in my details i have

```vue
<template>
  <div>
    <company-details :company="company" ></company-details>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
  import CompanyDetails from '../components/company/CompanyDetails'
  export default {
    created () {
      if (!this.company.companyName) {
        this.$store.dispatch('companyById', this.$route.params['id'])
      }
    },
    computed: {
      company () {
        return this.$store.getters.companyById(this.$route.params['id'])
      }
    },
    components: {
      'company-details': CompanyDetails
    }
  }
</script>
```

and then finally my companyDetails looks like this

```html
<template>
  <v-ons-col style="width: 350px; float:left;">
      <v-ons-card>
          <h1>{{company}}</h1>
      </v-ons-card>
    </v-ons-col>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['company']
  }
</script>
```

here is the mutations

```js
  export const companyMutations = {
    [ALL_COMPANYS] (state) {
      state.showLoader = true
    },
    [ALL_COMPANYS_SUCCESS] (state, payload) {
      state.showLoader = false
      state.companies = payload
    },
    [COMPANY_BY_ID] (state) {
      state.showLoader = true
    },
    [COMPANY_BY_ID_SUCCESS] (state, payload) {
      state.showLoader = false
      state.company = payload
    }
```

and here is my actions

```js
  allCompanies ({commit}) {
    commit(ALL_COMPANYS)
    axios.get(`${API_BASE}/companies`).then(response => {
      commit(ALL_COMPANYS_SUCCESS, response.data)
    })
  },
  companyById ({commit}, payload) {
    commit(COMPANY_BY_ID)
    axios.get(`${API_BASE}/companies/${payload}`).then(response => {
      console.log(payload, response.data)
      commit(COMPANY_BY_ID_SUCCESS, response.data)
    })
```

My CompanyList looks like this

```vue
  <template>
  <div>
    <div class="companies">
      <div class="container">
        <template v-for="company in companies" >
          <company :company="company" :key="company.id"></company>
        </template>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Company from './Company.vue'
  export default {
    name: 'companies',
    created () {
      if (this.companies.length === 0) {
        this.$store.dispatch('allCompanies')
      }
    },
    computed: {
      companies () {
        return this.$store.getters.allCompanies
      }
    },
    components: {
      'company': Company
    }
  }
</script>
```

Imported Company looks like this

```vue
<template>
    <v-ons-col style="width: 350px; float:left;">
            <router-link :to="'/details/'+company.id" class="company-link">
                <v-ons-card>
                    <img :src="company.imageURL" style="width:100% ;margin: 0 auto;display: block;">
                    <div class="title">
                        <b>{{company.companyName}}</b>
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        {{company.description}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                      <!-- <template v-for="company in companies">
                        {{company}}
                    </template> -->
                    </div>
                </v-ons-card>
            </router-link>
    </v-ons-col>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'company',
    props: ['company']
}
</script>
```

So when i click on one of these "companies" its suppose to get it by id and show the details however in the getters this return `getters.allCompanies.filter(c => c._id === id)[0]` returns undefined, when i refresh the page then it gets the correct company and displays it, what is going on please help. If you need more info please ask

Comment: I would spontanously assume that your `_id` field is a number, but `$route.params.id` is a string (because everyting taken from a path is a string), which means that your filter returns an empty result because he finds no matches.

Comment: when i log out the this.$route.params['id']   i get  a number

Comment: when i do this console.log(getters.allCompanies.filter(c => c._id)) i get [], and when i do  console.log(getters.allCompanies.filter(c => c._id === id)[0]) i get undefined

Comment: Where do you initialize allCompanies?

Comment: Please have a look at the updated question i have added my mutations and actions

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question, where do you call `allCompanies` action?

Comment: @fatman i call allCompanies in the companyList.vue file and the it gets passed as a prop to company which has a router link with a dynamic route

Comment: well, then maybe `_id` is a string? The thing is: When you naviagte to a page with `router-link` and pass a number as a param, it will be a number in `$route.params`. When you navigate to it from the URL bar (or refresh the page) it will be a string, because the path is a string, no numbers are tyepcasted.

That would explain why it works on refresh (comparing string <> string), but not on programmatic navigation (comparing string <> number)

Comment: @LinusBorg thanks for the reply, would you perhaps know how i can fix this? thank you

Comment: @LinusBorg thanks for your help You where correct was comparing string to number. id was a string and you where right it comes from the url and _id was n number so what i did was `getters.allCompanies.filter(c => c._id.toString() === id)[0]`